# How to send lotus notes email using C#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need to send a simple lotus notes email using C#. I have already tried using the code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29442/Send-Lotus-Notes-Email-Using-C) but it is not working. I get this error:

> The exception unknown software exception (0xe0434f4d) occured in the
>   application at location 0x7c812afb

Any ideas?

Comment: What line of code is throwing that error?

Answer (score 1):

Under the build options for your project, make sure that you set the platform target to 'x86' (not 'Any CPU' and not 'x64' - the Domino library is only compatible with 'x86').

If you must target x64, then you'll need to isolate all of your Domino code into a separate x86 project then call that code from your x64 project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct permissions to the COM file you're referencing.  Perhaps give read permissions to Everyone just to rule that out.